# calculate the cdf

Tags: probability

The continuous random variable $R$ has the following probability density function on the sample space $−1 \le r \le 1$,
$$f(r)=\begin{cases} \frac{1}{4} \hspace{.5cm} \text{for} \hspace{.5cm} −1 ≤ r ≤ 0\\
 r+\frac{1}{4}  \hspace{.5cm} \text{for} \hspace{.5cm}  0 < r ≤ 1 \\
      0  \hspace{.5cm}            \text{else}
\end{cases}$$

￼Calculate

- **A**. $P \{− 2 ≤ R ≤ 2 \}$.
- **B**. $FR(t)$, for $t$ from $-2$ to $2$.
- **C**. $E(\frac{R^3}{6})$.

So for part a, I already took the integral and get the following CDF:

$$f(r)=\begin{cases} \frac{1}{4}r \hspace{.5cm} \text{for} \hspace{.5cm} −1 ≤ r ≤ 0\\
 \frac{1}{2}(r^2)+\frac{1}{4}r  \hspace{.5cm} \text{for} \hspace{.5cm}  0 < r ≤ 1 \\
      0  \hspace{.5cm}            \text{else}
\end{cases}$$

And I got that the probability between $-1/2$ to $1/2$ is $\frac{3}{8}$, which is $0.3750$.
But for part **B** and **C**, I am not sure how to solve it.

Comment: Did you notice that your $F(r)$ has value $\frac 14r = -\frac 14$ when $r = -1$? and indeed $F(r) < 0$ for $r < 0$. Does this cause you any concern at all?

Comment: Are you talking about my solutions for part a? Or are you giving the hint for part b?

Comment: I am talking about "So for part (a), I already took the integral and get..." .  $F(r)$, which _by definition_ is the probability of the event $\{X \leq r\}$, has negative value for $r < 0$. Does this bother you at all? Also, since $X$ takes on values between $-1$ and $+1$ only, and you found $P\{-2 \leq X \leq 2\} = \frac 38$, does _this_ cause you any concern?

Comment: @Christie What have you done to get the cdf ? It looks like, that you just have copied the pdf. The only difference is $1/4r$ instead of $1/4$

Comment: sorry for that. I copied the problem wrong. The integral part should be right now.

Comment: It seems that all the format has been changed and also the numbers. I don't know why. Sorry for the confusion. Now the problem and the solution for part a should looks better.

Comment: @Christie You have found the _antiderivative_; you need to find the _integral_, a.k.a. the _area_ under the pdf curve to the left of $r$.